# Hyphens or no hyphens in well(-)thought(-)through?

Tags: hyphens, compounds, attributives

Which of the following is the correct form?

1. well thought through
2. well thought-through
3. well-thought-through

I've tried googling, and all three seem to occur to quite some extent, but does that mean that all three are correct?

Comment: Related: [Which is correct? dubious looking + noun Or dubious-looking + noun?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/269743/which-is-correct-dubious-looking-noun-or-dubious-looking-noun)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using this phrase attibutively, then hyphens seem useful

> That was a well-thought-through idea!

If not, then hyphens seem unnecessary:

> That idea was well thought through.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, "thought through" is a [phrasal verb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/think%20through), not an adjective, so spelling it with a hyphen would not be standard English grammar. An adjective with a very similar meaning is [**thought-out**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thought-out), which you'll note *is* normally spelled with a hyphen. Furthermore, [well-thought-out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well-thought-out) is itself a commonly used adjective.